# How to extract values from log file simultaneously while a process is running in django view

Tags: python, django, progress-bar

To update my progress bar, i need to compute the percentage of progress of a process running in my django view, to do this; i have to retrieve some values simultaneously from a log file generated while this one is running so that i can compute the percetage equivalent to 0/5000, 19/5000... as shown in the picture.
I'm new to django and programming in general.
How can I do that please in a function in my django views.py? or if there is a way to it with javascript will be also good solution. Thank you in advance.
The log file which is generated looks like this:

[image]

Comment: What is this process? How do you run it?

Comment: @DanielRosemanIit 's a command in a bash script run by subprocess in my django view that do some process on an input video.

Comment: If the call to subprocess is non blocking, you could have a separate view that reads the log file and calculates your progress, which you would then poll using js in the browser. That would be the most naive implementation anyway. You might also want to look into task queues (like celery for example) for doing this kind of long processing in response to web requests.

Comment: @DavyKavanagh , yes your first suggestion is what i want to do; the problem is that i don't know how to get those values with red simultaneously while they are generated in a django view, if you have an idea about it tell me please.

Comment: If the log file is on the same file system as django is running, you should just be able to read the log file, using a regular expression to pull out only the lines and data you need, but you will have to iterate over all lines each time you calculate percentage. What _might_ be better is when this long running process is started you could start a second process which watches the log file and will do the calculation for you. A simple awk one liner could work, piped to another file could work. Then django could read only the last line of that file. cont.d...

Comment: cont.d: ... that's not a stable solution though. You'd be better off having some process that watches your log file, calculates the progress, posts the result to a django endpoint, and then have some push mechanism to get the data back to the browser. @glenfant is right, websockets are desinged for such things.

Answer (score 0):

You should consider using Websockets based co-frameworks to make real time notifications to user behind the browsers. These are built for such usage.

Have a try with Django-Channels https://channels.readthedocs.io/en/stable/ or Crossbar+Autobahn http://crossbar.io/

I made a small Django + Crossbar "Real time" polls demo here https://github.com/alterway/wamp-polls